# Python unit tests: TestCaseSource

Tags: django, unit-testing, nose

I am new to python development, specifically Django pipeline. I am used to nunit testing framework where I have tools such as the [TestCaseData class](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5).

we are currently using the nose framework with the django.test modules.

**heres my question:** is there a module or some component that does the same thing for python/django code?

Comment: holy cow. just found the following blog. great stuff! http://defragdev.com/blog/?p=660

Comment: I have also found that nose has updated their parameterized tests to work friendly with the base class unittest!
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-parameterized/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after researching a fair bit, I decided to use nose-parameterized. it works in both functional tests, and class based tests, and I can provide it a static method to supply test cases that are programmatically generated like the following:

```
def test_case_source():
    parameters = []
    for i in range(0,10):
        parameters.append(('test{0}'.format(i), i))
    return parameters

class TestTestCaseSource(TestCase):
    @parameterized.expand(test_case_source())
    def test_my_fake_test(self, test_name, param):
        self.assertEquals(param, param)
```